# Codesign check fails : ... *.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid > file added

Tags: ios, jenkins, code-signing

I am producing an automated build with Jenkins using the Xcode Integration plugin.

The problem is that the console log produces this error:

```
Codesign check fails : /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/Obfuscated.app
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/Base.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/de.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/el.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/en.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/es.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/fr.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/it.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/ja.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/nl.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/pt-PT.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/pt.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/ru.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/sv.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/th.lproj/IASKLocalizable.strings
file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obf/jobs/iOS/jobs/Obfuscated/workspace/build/Obfuscated.app/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/InAppSettingsKit.bundle/tr.lproj/IASKLocalizable.string
```

This doesn't actually fail the build in Jenkins so be warned!

I've double and triple checked the code signing on the machine and in the Jenkins config file.

What's going on here? I don't understand why these files are getting added.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how the .app has an extra .app in it?

This means the app is being built twice.

Once for the .xcarchive and once for the .ipa.

Unchecking the "Generate Archive?" Jenkins Xcode plugin setting fixes the issue.

I'm not sure why it can't do both at the moment.